# Ubuntu slow to boot after dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just installed Kali Linux (on `/dev/sda5`) in dual boot with Ubuntu (on /dev/sda2). However, now that I have Kali, Ubuntu takes a few minutes to launch, whereas Kali takes a few seconds, and I would like the contrary. How can I do that ?

## Edit

Here is my `/etc/fstab` in Ubuntu :

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=7d4d2f18-146c-4d56-b5f3-0dc605eeb9e0 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=95B2-5AED  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=69d6623e-0bcc-4cef-8b25-e46c98210d44 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=97913f94-1989-4c8d-b2e0-010dfb10d613 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  I have no idea, but I'd explore what you changed in installing Kali. Did you create the sda5 partition? or was it there before (*primarily did you reformat it? it was accessed before in your file-system table causing Ubuntu to try & mount a now non-existing partition until it's reaches timeout as your description implies to me*).  We can't know what changes you made in the installation of Kali, but I'd looked at sda5 changes if I was in your position.

Comment: When I installed Kali, I had already created the `sda5` partition and formated it in ext4. During the installation, I removed the formating of `sda5` to have 30Gb of free space, and installed Kali on it.

Comment: My point was the formatting changed the UUID (or unique-ID of the partition which is created during format), and your Ubuntu is likely to look for & wait for the UUID of the old-partition, then eventually time-out....   ie. you need to change the UUID of your old partition, with that of the newly formatted partition.  You've not amended it to reflect your new layout causing the timeouts...  The first place I'd look is your file-system-table (/etc/fstab)...

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you told me, but I added to my post the contents of my `/etc/fstab`, and I tried replacing the UUID of `sda2` with the one of `sda5`, but it didn't help

Comment: Don't just replace or change UUIDs without checking that the UUID's match your partition UUID's.  If you `sudo blkid |grep UUID` you'll get a list of UUID's found on your system, use these [results] to check the UUIDs mentioned in your fstab are correct (I cannot as I don't know what's on your system). I don't see sda5 mentioned in comments (lines which have a # at the start are comments or documentation) but I'd still check them all.  Installations (ie. kali) often re-format swap; so you may have found this has changed, and may be your problem.

Comment: Thanks guiverc, now Ubuntu takes 45 seconds to launch. It's stall not as good as before, but it's better. Can anyone make it even faster ?

Comment: A rebuild of initramfs is I think your next step; I think it has UUID's built into it (`update-initramfs`). Next i would probably rebuild grub (`update-grub` which usually uses PARTUUID, but it's quick & simple).   I don't think initrd will contain them ....

Comment: Rebuilding initramfs did the job perfectly, now Ubuntu takes less than 10 seconds to launch ! Thanks a lot, that's perfect !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

I'd suggest exploring what you changed in installing Kali. Did you create the sda5 partition? or was it there before (*primarily did you reformat it? it was accessed before in your file-system table causing Ubuntu to try & mount a now non-existing partition until it's reaches timeout as your description implies to me*). We can't know what changes you made in the installation of Kali, but I'd look at 'sda5' changes if I was in your position.

If you re-formatted 'sda5' you'll have changed the UUID (or unique-ID of the partition; created during format), and your Ubuntu is likely looking and waiting for the UUID of the old-partition *to appear*, then eventually time-out.... ie. you need to change the UUID of your old partition, to that of the newly formatted partition. You've not amended it to reflect your new layout causing the timeouts... The first place I'd look is your file-system-table (`/etc/fstab`)..

Don't just replace or change UUIDs without checking that the UUID's match your partition UUID's. If you `sudo blkid |grep UUID` you'll get a list of UUID's found on your system, use these [results] to check the UUIDs mentioned in your fstab are correct. I don't see sda5 mentioned in comments (*lines which have a # at the start are comments or documentation*) but I'd still check them all. Installations (ie. kali) often re-format swap; so you may have found this has changed, and this may be your issue causing slow boots.

A rebuild of `initramfs` is your next step; I think it has UUID's built into it (`update-initramfs`). If boots are still slow, next i would probably rebuild grub (`update-grub` but this usually uses PARTUUID, but is quick and simple to re-create).

(*this answer is just copied/pasted comments with minor editing*)